# SQL that filters records that match specific conditions from time series data

Tags: sql, presto

There is a table in which data of the video viewing log as follows is stored.

```
|user_id| status |     time         |
-------------------------------------
|user_a |start   |2019-06-18 00:00:00|
|user_a |progress|2019-06-18 00:00:05|
|user_a |progress|2019-06-18 00:00:10|
|user_a |complete|2019-06-18 00:00:15|
|user_a |start   |2019-06-18 00:10:00|
|user_a |complete|2019-06-18 00:10:05|
|user_b |start   |2019-06-18 00:20:00|
|user_b |progress|2019-06-18 00:20:05|
|user_b |progress|2019-06-18 00:20:10|
```

"start" is a video viewing start flag, 
"progress" is a video viewing flag, and 
"complete" is a video viewing completion flag.

The complete flag is not always set because the video may not be watched.

However, in certain cases, the complete flag may be set without progress.

I want to exclude from the above data records that have only start and complete (no progress).

Specifically, I want to exclude the following records.

```
|user_a |start   |2019-06-18 00:10:00|
|user_a |complete|2019-06-18 00:10:05|
```

Is there a way to do this with sql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lead()` and `lag()`:

```
select *
from (select t.*,
             lag(status) over (partition by user_id order by time) as prev_status,
             lead(status) over (partition by user_id order by time) as next_status
      from t
     ) t
where not ((status = 'start' and next_status = 'complete') or
           (status = 'complete' and prev_status = 'start')
          );
```

Alternatively, given your sample data, you can use:

```
where 'progress' in (prev_status, status, next_status);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lead()` and `lag()` window analytic functions :

```
select user_id, status, time 
  from
  (
   select lag(status,1,'x') over (order by time) lg,
          lead(status,1,'x') over (order by time) ld,
          t.*
     from t
   ) t2
 where not ( lg = ld and status in ('start','complete'))
```

I showed the <kbd>[Demo](https://rextester.com/OBQZ47803)</kbd> within fiddle for `SQL Server DB`